# iOS Navigation bar title truncated after updating it once

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

Fixed by changing the title update line to:

```
self.title = ""
self.title = "\(currentQuestion+1)/\(gameObject!.results.count)"
```

---

After messing around with constraints to find a good look on every iPhone device, my navigation bar title has ran into an interesting problem. I am making it track the current question in a trivia app but it seems to cut off(I believe the correct word is truncate) the last part of the text after I update it once.

The first time I load a new game view and call a function that contains:

```
self.navigationItem.title = "Current question: \(currentQuestion+1)/\(gameObject!.results.count)"
```

The view loads in the first question like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkbKp.png

Once I press the next question button and use the exact same function, it ends up like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRDfd.png

**I am not changing views, simply updating labels and buttons.**

It was working fine this morning so I assume it has something to do with constraints that I messed with. There's also something weird going on with the xCode simulator's clock. It sometimes gets cut off as well and shows something like 2... instead of 2:30. This happens after a minute or so. No amount of interacting will change when or how it happens, it just does.

Clock Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMzUS.png

Comment: can you add code sample, where do you calling this code? And also, how you change the question?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it and edited the post to reflect that.